# Visual Studio 2017 Express "deletes" the summarys of all Methods after PC restart

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, visual-studio-2017, metadata

In VS Express 2017. My problem is when I'm using some methods like "Directory.CreateDirectory()" there is no method description. If I press F12 at this method, I see the metadata and there are no Summarys above the methods.

I already deleted and reinstalled the .Net Framework, after this the method descriptions where there, but after PC restart they where disappeared.

How to fix that?

Comment: While version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework 4.8 Developer Pack.

Comment: @Luuke,based on my test, I could not reproduce your problem even if I installed. I suggest that you can start the vs2017 in in safe mode by referring to [SafeMode (devenv.exe))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019). If it still exists the problem, I suggest that you can ask it in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to report a problem.